# Does pinning lots of apps to the start causes battery draining

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

I recently added more apps to the start and now I see battery usage is 17% per hour for near idle usage. This make me depressed !

So may the reason is installing more apps, or adding them to the start, or neither? ( except one or two of them, others aren't allowed for background tasks)

I have Lumia 920 /WP8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More apps pinned doesn't pinned to the start screen does not mean more battery drain. Since you are running Windows Phone 8, there is an [extra ability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that pinned apps get:

> If the Tile for your app is pinned to the phone’s Start screen, the
>   expiration time for your background agent schedule is automatically
>   extended to two weeks whenever your background agent calls to update the Tile.

In otherwords, as long as apps that are pinned behave, their background tasks do not get cancelled after two weeks of inactivity like other apps in your all apps menu.

But these apps get at most 25 seconds every 20-40 minutes. This would NOT cause a large battery drain. Also these apps still have to behave and fall within a bunch of other guidelines in order to keep running in the background.

Microsoft has gone to great lengths to give developers the tools they need to give users apps they want to use, but at the same time, prevent abuse that would cause a bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely drains the battery if the tile size is set to medium and large. keep the not so required apps size to Small and it wil be just like an ICON so it wont update itself. That will not drainthe battery at all. Hope this helps.

Comment: The size of the tile has no impact on the usage the rights or the power used by an app. The only thing that is different is that more space is used on the screen. The app goes through identical logic which means no additional cpu cycles are taken to generate or maintain the image. Even if a developer decided to go through some intensive way to generate images for large tiles it is limited in how long long how often and how much memory it uses to do so. In the worst case scenario, it would use up a few extra microseconds of battery life. If the did that, they probably would do it for small too.

Comment: I think what he means is that the large tile version of apps have more functionality, e.g. live updates etc, whereas as the small tiles don't usually, they are just a static image (ICON he calls it), rather than a dynamic tile.